# Android Studio doesn't pause on breakpoint within OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio

I've noticed that if I set a breakpoint in an OnClickListener, such as:

```
    mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // breakpoint goes here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

execution doesn't get halted, even though the Toast will display. Breakpoints work else in my code. Halp!

Comment: it is not empty, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not empty - I just tried to keep the example simple. I'll update the question to indicate that there is, indeed, code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breakpoints have to be on executable code. You could make a log statement or even a random variable declaration.

Comment: This was the problem! I kept setting breakpoints on empty lines between my code. When I switched to setting them on a line containing executable code, then it stops. Phew! I thought I was going crazy :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You need to put some code in there for it to work. I normally just put this line of code in to get a breakpoint to work.

```
Log.d("", "");
```

Comment: In [Android Studio](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-method-breakpoints.html) (or IntelliJ, to be more precise) as well as [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-set_method_breakpoints.htm) you can also have *method breakpoints*, so no need to add any dummy code for a *line breakpoint*. Adding a method breakpoint in AS/IJ will display a warning about a potential slowdown of the debugging process, but I suppose having a debugger attached by itself already does that trick. :)

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that there is actually code when I've tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `Log.d` or set breakpoint on blockquote `{`